# Filtering a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Source list of dictionaries

```
[
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val1'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val2'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('333333333333333'), 'key1': 'val3'}, 
    {'main_id': 4, '_id': ObjectId('444444444444444'), 'key1': 'val4'},
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val5'},
]
```

filtered list of dictionaries

```
[
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val1'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val2'}, 
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val3'},
]
```

I want to get a new list of dictionaries:

```
[
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('333333333333333'), 'key1': 'val3'}, 
    {'main_id': 4, '_id': ObjectId('444444444444444'), 'key1': 'val4'},
]
```

in other words, I want a new list to contain values that don't exist in a filtered list.
Your ideas?

Comment: In your example, the filtered list is not a subset of the first list.  Why?

Comment: I think `val3` is supposed to be `val5` in the filtered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
result = [s for s in original if s not in filtered]
```

---

or use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x: x not in filtered, original)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
full = [
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val1'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val2'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('333333333333333'), 'key1': 'val3'}, 
    {'main_id': 4, '_id': ObjectId('444444444444444'), 'key1': 'val4'},
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val5'},
]
filtered = [
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val6'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val7'}, 
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val8'},
]

diff = [x for x in full if x not in filtered]
```

Comment: It would probably be best to copy ``filtered`` into a set first, as the membership checks will be significantly faster. (Obviously, it depends on what the size of the input will be and what the needs are for performance/memory use).

Comment: Ah, CPU versus RAM. The classic duel.

Comment: but it would not allow you to copy this to set - will throw dict obj is unhashable.

Answer (score 0):

Using original data:

```
# dummy!
ObjectId = str


original = [
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val1'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val2'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('333333333333333'), 'key1': 'val3'}, 
    {'main_id': 4, '_id': ObjectId('444444444444444'), 'key1': 'val4'},
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val5'},
]

filtered = [
    {'main_id': 0, '_id': ObjectId('111111111111111'), 'key1': 'val1'}, 
    {'main_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('222222222222222'), 'key1': 'val2'}, 
    {'main_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('555555555555555'), 'key1': 'val3'},
]

new_list = [d for d in original if d not in filtered]

print(new_list)
```